# JavaScript Image Popup Window

Tags: javascript, html, image, popup, window

I would like to setup my gallery web page so that when a user clicks on the thumbnail image, a window pops up displaying a larger view of the image.  I do not mean a pop up window as in a browser window but a window that is loaded within that same page and can be closed.  I am not exactly sure how I would go about doing this.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See Lightbox2. http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/

Comment: Thank you.  My web host (currently free) does not allow AJAX and this works perfectly.  Thank you again.

Answer (score 2):

If you can use jQuery I would recommend

[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/)

These are also very good

[Fancybox](http://fancybox.net/)

[Pirobox](http://www.pirolab.it/pirobox/)

[Nyromodal](http://nyromodal.nyrodev.com/)

[ImageBox](http://www.intelliance.fr/jquery/imagebox/)

Answer (score 0):

And a third option: [jQuery Tools overlay](http://flowplayer.org/tools/overlay.html)

Answer (score 0):

I believe the technique you're after is a [lightbox](http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) (I think it was the first of these).

[Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/) is an awesome jQuery based clone, or there's about a [million others out there](http://www.google.com.au/search?rlz=1C1CHMG_en-USAU291AU304&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=lightbox+clone) :-)

Answer (score 0):

Much advance option would be [Magnific](http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/) Or [Gettopup](http://gettopup.com/)